# Split string into array using regular expression "[element1][element2]"

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
var search = "[title|Asc][description|Desc]";
```

I'd like an array of:

```
[
    "title|Asc",
    "description|Desc"
]
```

I've tried various reg ex, but i just don't understand it enough.

```
var matches = search.split(/[^a-zA-Z0-9|]/);
```

Any chance i can have some help?

Comment: Just use `split()` function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split` and `filter`

```
var output = search.split(/[\[\]]+/).filter( s => s.length > 0 );
```

**Demo**

```js
var search = "[title|Asc][description|Desc]";
var output = search.split(/[\[\]]+/).filter( s => s.length > 0 );
console.log(output);
```

**Explanation**

- `split` by `/[\[\]]+/`, which is a one or more occurrence of character class of `[]`
- `filter` out empty items.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. Do you have time to explain how it works a bit?

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 Sure, I'll add an explanation

Comment: @gurvinder372 you don't need to escape the `[` in the set. Also, the `+` is in the wrong spot: `[[\]]+`. As it currently stands, you'll be splitting on the `+` character too.

Comment: @ctwheels You are right about where + should be, I don't think `[]` shouldn't be escaped in the set.

Comment: @gurvinder372 only the `]` needs to be since that's what's determining what *ends* the character class. You already started it with `[`, so adding `[` in the character class will not do anything special, just match `[` literally. It's not a necessary change, just more of an FYI. Some find it more legible to leave it escaped in the set.

Comment: @ctwheels Understood, thanks. However, I will keep the answer **as is** (keep the escaped `[]`) for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first and last `[`, `]` and then split by `][`

`search.substring(1,search.length-1).split('][')`

```js
var search = "[title|Asc][description|Desc]";

console.log(search.substring(1,search.length-1).split(']['))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use a `match` instead of `split` to make sure we match string between `[` and `]`:

```js
const regex = /\[([^\]]*)\]/g;
const str = `[title|Asc][description|Desc]`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
   console.log(m[1]);
}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qe2gbJ/1)